# java.lang.IllegalStateException: cardProductItem must not be null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-cardview

I have create an android app with Kotlin.This app contains an interface, which contains a recyclerview to get all the list of product. 
To fill this list of product, i create an adapter, this adapter is a cardview : Imageview and two textview. 
In this interface, i added two buttons, one when i click on all the product display with the list and the other one display with grid disposition.The default value for grid disposition. 
I wsant to change the width and the height of a cardview, to display all the product in the List. 
The following code is anadapter item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cardProductItem"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_medium"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_middle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_middle"
        android:background="@color/grey">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/productImage"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_middle">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/productName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/productPrice"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium"

                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/arrowDetailProduct"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_right_arrow"/>

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

the following code is an extract from an xml file which cotains a recyclerview :

```
<ImageView
               android:id="@+id/gridProducts"
               android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
               android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
               android:scaleType="fitXY"
               android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/productNumber"
               android:layout_margin="8dp"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_divided_squares"/>
       <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/listProducts"
               android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
               android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
               android:scaleType="fitXY"
               android:layout_margin="8dp"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_rounded_black_square_shape"/>

   </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>


   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
           android:id="@+id/recyclerViewProductByCategory"
           android:layout_below="@+id/recyclerViewCategories"
           android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_middle"
           android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_middle"
           android:orientation="horizontal"/>
```

the following code contains the onclick acion into the two buttom(Imageview) :

```
gridProducts.setOnClickListener {
            recyclerViewProductByCategory.layoutManager =
                StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
            recyclerViewProductByCategory.adapter = products?.let { it -> ProductAdapter(it) }
            gridProducts.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            listProducts.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        }
        listProducts.setOnClickListener {
            recyclerViewProductByCategory.layoutManager =
                LinearLayoutManager(this@CategoryByProduct, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)

            recyclerViewProductByCategory.adapter = products?.let { it -> ProductAdapter(it) }
    val layoutParams = LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, // CardView width
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT // CardView height
    )
    cardProductItem.layoutParams = layoutParams
            listProducts.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            gridProducts.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        }
```

after running my app an exception appear as the following :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: cardProductItem must not be null

could you please tell me where's the error and how can i correct it

Comment: can you post also your layout?

Comment: post complete code for both the recyclerviews(listProducts and recyclerViewProductByCategory), and also the data object

Comment: any help please

Comment: where do you initialize `recyclerViewProductByCategory` and `cardProductItem`? can you post also the complete activity/fragment code?

Comment: I change some thing in my question, could you please see the modification and tell me how can i make my code functional

Comment: Did you solve this? I have same problem!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code available, you are setting the value of `cardProductItem` outside of `setOnClickListener`. The error is stating that `cardProductItem` can not be set when a `listProduct` is clicked. Make sure that you are setting `cardProductItem` to a value before the UI is presented to the user.

For a more in-depth answer, I would need to look at the other places where `cardProductItem` is used.

Comment: I make some modification in my post, could you please see it again

Comment: Can you post the file that contains the onClickListener call? It's tough to tell where you are initializing `cardProductItem`.